# 'Refused to display [community page URL] in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: community-builder

I just moved my community from my dev sandbox to a UAT sandbox. Now in community builder none of my login pages will display and I get a screen like below:

[image: Community builder display]

When looking in the console in Chrome I see the below:
[image: Chrome error console]

I am confused as to why this would be happening. There is no VF on this page (clickjack protection is enabled anyway). It is a simple login form. This page works fine when logging in and out of the community. This error also happens for all the login pages (login error, forgot password etc). All other pages load correctly in the builder.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but it may help the others who recently got the same issue. I fixed it by empty the trash can in Site.com Studio.

Please try these:

1. Go to Setup, type "All Communities" in Quick Find and click it.
2. Click Workspaces | Administration | Pages | Go to Site.com Studio.
3. Access Trash Can.
4. Open the browser console and go to the console tab.

- For Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge, hit the F12 key
- For Mozilla Firefox, hit Ctrl+Shift+J
- For Safari browsers, go to Develop | Show Error Console

5. Put this command after ">" and press Enter or execute it: `PicassoWebServices.ManageSite.EmptyTrashCan()`
6. Refresh the Trash Can or open it again, you should see that it is empty.

Thanks to the original post:  https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lWB3QAM